# Cake How to Run Specific Test Category

Tags: cakebuild

I was wondering if it was possible to run a specific test category? I want to be able to do this equivalently in Cake:

`dotnet test --filter TestCategory="foo"`

Unsure of how to go about it in Cake, I did notice `DotNetCoreTestSettings` but not sure how to set the category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `Filter` is a property of `DotNetCoreTestSettings` class, I would expect the following to cover your requirements (similar to the [sample found here](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore/DotNetCoreAliases/8191BBC4)):

```
 var settings = new DotNetCoreTestSettings
 {
     Configuration = "Release",
     Filter = "TestCategory=\"foo\""
 };

 DotNetCoreTest("./test/Project.Tests/", settings);
```

Comment: You can see where the arguments for this are constructed here: https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/develop/src/Cake.Common/Tools/DotNetCore/Test/DotNetCoreTester.cs#L83-L88